# ContourPlot U^2+W^2=V^2 -> V(U), where U, V solutions of equation from special functions

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

CountourPlot W(U)
[image]
I have this following code of it:

```
eps1 = 2;
eps2 = 1.5;
n = 0;
\[Delta] = 1/2 (1 - eps2/eps1);

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[{(D[BesselJ[n, U], 
         U]/(BesselJ[n, U] * U) + (1 - 2*\[Delta])/W  * 
        D[BesselK[n, W], W]/(BesselK[n, W] ))*
     (D[BesselJ[n, U], U]/(BesselJ[n, U] * U) + 
       1/W  * D[BesselK[n, W], W]/(BesselK[n, W] )) ==  0}], {U, 1, 
  10}, {W, 1, 9}, WorkingPrecision -> 10, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 150]
```

but I need to plot as following V(U), where V=Sqrt(U^2+W^2)

If I put W = Sqrt[V^2 - U^2] in eq like this:

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[{(D[BesselJ[n, U], 
         U]/(BesselJ[n, U] * U) + (1 - 2*\[Delta])/Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]  * 
        D[BesselK[n, Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]], 
          Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]]/(BesselK[n, Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]] ))*
     (D[BesselJ[n, U], U]/(BesselJ[n, U] * U) + 
       1/Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]  * 
        D[BesselK[n, Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]], 
          Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]]/(BesselK[n, Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]] )) ==  
    0}], {U, 1, 10}, {V, 1, 15}, WorkingPrecision -> 10, 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 150]
```

I'll get this picture, where is nothing...
[image]
I actually don't understand, how to do it. Pls help

Comment: Use `ParametricPlot`? Can you expand on your problem a bit more and add some context?

Comment: Just substitute in the expression that you are plotting that $W=\pm\sqrt{V^2-U^2}$ taking care the sign.

Comment: @yarchik, this way doesn't help

Comment: @MarcoB, ok I added some more information

Comment: `D[BesselK[n, Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]], Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]]` is incorrect code, as Mathematica states whey it is executed.  Instead, try `D[BesselK[n, z], z] /. z -> Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]`.

Comment: Works for me. But you need to analyze your expression, there are singularities, moreover if $U>V$ square root will be imaginary. You first need to compute the derivative and then substitute. Just invest a little bit of work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ContourPlot3D` for `U^2+W^2==V^2` and `f[U,V]` as `MeshFunction` sine the plot is the intersection of `U^2+W^2==V^2` and `f[U,V]==0`.

```
Clear[f];
eps1 = 2;
eps2 = 1.5;
n = 0;
δ = 1/2 (1 - eps2/eps1);
f[U_, W_] = (D[BesselJ[n, U], U]/(BesselJ[n, U]*U) + (1 - 2*δ)/
       W*D[BesselK[n, W], W]/(BesselK[n, W]))*(D[BesselJ[n, U], 
       U]/(BesselJ[n, U]*U) + 1/W*D[BesselK[n, W], W]/(BesselK[n, W]));
ContourPlot3D[U^2 + W^2 == V^2, {U, 0, 10}, {V, -10, 10}, {W, 0, 10}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{U, V, W}, f[U, W] // Evaluate], 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, ContourStyle -> None, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, AxesLabel -> {"U", "V", None}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}, PlotPoints -> 150, 
 MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

The same as ( We use  `{V, U, 10}` in order to set `V>U`)

```
ContourPlot[
 f[U, W] == 0 /. W -> Sqrt[V^2 - U^2] // Evaluate, {U, 0, 10}, {V, U, 
  10}, PlotPoints -> 150, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]